# Eclipse Android Emulator

Tags: android, eclipse

Recently I tried to learn Android programming. I installed Eclipse, Android SDK, almost 10 GB of data with SDK Manager. I create new project and AVD. When I run the code, all I see on the console is this :

```
[2015-02-18 20:16:27 - Hey] ------------------------------
[2015-02-18 20:16:27 - Hey] Android Launch!
[2015-02-18 20:16:27 - Hey] adb is running normally.
[2015-02-18 20:16:27 - Hey] Performing com.example.hey.MainActivity activity launch
[2015-02-18 20:16:27 - Hey] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'AndroidEmu' is not available. Launching new emulator.
[2015-02-18 20:16:27 - Hey] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'AndroidEmu'
[2015-02-18 20:16:45 - Hey] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2015-02-18 20:16:45 - Hey] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
```

And all I see is emulator with android logo. I waited almost half an hour, I tried almost every method on internet, I am working on this problem since yesterday and now I am completely stuck.

I have 32-Bit Windows 7, 4 GB RAM, Intel Core 2Duo CPU. I have an old computer, is this the problem?

I really need help, I want to learn Android so much but thanks to these problems, I couldn't try anything.

Comment: You are better off using a real test device. You can get a cheap phone/tablet. Or use genymotion but I would still recommend at least one real device. Also, you should be using Android Studio instead of Eclipse, especially if you are just starting out.

Comment: I installed Android Studio too but it run same emulator and result is same

Comment: That's why I recommended using a real device or genymotion. But nothing is going to be a real device. The default emulators are known to be slow among other issues you may run into.

Comment: @codeMagic If I just copy apk file to my phone, will it work correctly?

Comment: If your app works. But you can plug the device into your computer and run it right from your IDE

Comment: how can I run it right from my IDE?

Comment: Plug it into the [usb port](https://www.google.com/search?q=usb+port&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=955&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=9tzkVL2TIcuigwTp0YHgAw&ved=0CDcQsAQ) on your computer, click the "Run" button on your IDE, pray. This may also be helpful http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html

Comment: I will try it as soon as possible. I think you have a lot of knowledge about Android programming, can I ask you more questions on somewhere like email?

Comment: These comments don't really show an extensive knowledge. It's just a basic part of the documentation. If you have more questions, feel free to post them on SO (and be sure to follow the guidelines for posting) and myself or someone else will be happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Android Emulator is known for being really slow. I would recommend you to take a look at Genymotion.  https://www.genymotion.com/ 
It's a lot better experience.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to try your own real device as per my opinion

Answer (score 0):

Please consider trying Android Studio instead of Eclipse. It is the newer and officially supported IDE for android development. Doing so will allow you to use HAXM, which is Intel's tool to allow your emulator to make use of hardware acceleration. You should see considerable speed improvements with it.

https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows

Comment: I tried that too but I got an error. I forgot the error and couldn't find it again